# How can a US Citizen lose citizenship?

Tags: united-states, citizenship

I recall reading that it is very difficult to lose U.S. citizenship. For example, that you can pledge alliance to another country and still remain a U.S. citizen. Is this true?

If this is the case, what are the circumstances in which a US Citizen can lose citizenship?

Comment: @ColleenV that is not correct.  Since *Afroyim v. Rusk* in 1967, it has been virtually impossible for a US citizen to lose that citizenship voluntarily, and the US has no prohibition against its citizens having other citizenship.

Comment: Did you look online?  The US state department has a pretty comprehensive page on this topic that is easily found in a web search.

Comment: @phoog I believe you meant "lose it *involuntarily*;" you can voluntarily lose it pretty easily (walk into a US embassy or consulate abroad and make an explicit declaration you are renouncing citizenship).

Comment: @cpast you are correct, I meant to type "involuntarily."

Comment: @Colleen. I knew a family that had citizenship in China, New Zealand, and the US. New Zealand was original, the other two acquired. I am confident there are people with more countries. Keeping track of the laws must be a challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of potentially expatriating acts may be found at https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality.html

As the page explains, one will lose one's citizenship when performing one of these acts *with the intention of losing one's US citizenship.*  In most cases, the presumption is that such intention *does not exist.*

One obvious exception is an explicit renunciation of citizenship before a consular officer.  The others are accepting a "policy-level position" in a foreign government, serving in a foreign military engaged in hostilities with the US, and committing treason.

Comment: Even in some of the latter cases, you don't necessarily lose US citizenship. The current Mayor of London (Boris Johnson) was a US citizen until earlier this year, despite being the Mayor of London (which is certainly a policy-level position).

Comment: @cpast First, for a policy-level position, the *presumption of intent* is handled differently, which means the process of evaluating the person's intent is different.  It does not mean that the loss of citizenship is automatic.  Second, Mayor of London is certainly *not* a "policy-level position in the government of a foreign state," which is the actual wording in the US code.  It is a position in the government of a foreign municipality.  See http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/120540.pdf and http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/uscode/8/12/III/III

Comment: @cpast: "was a US citizen until earlier this year" Do you have evidence that he is not still a US citizen?

Comment: @user102008 http://www.forbes.com/sites/robertwood/2015/02/15/savvy-london-mayor-boris-johnson-paid-irs-is-now-renouncing-u-s-citizenship/#290075426c70

Comment: @cpast: It doesn't say he has actually renounced.

Comment: @user There were many contemporary news stories saying he intended to renounce. Do you have a source saying he *didn't*?

Comment: @cpast: He said he intended to renounce in 2006 too, and apparently didn't. So his own claims are not very trustworthy. The names of people who renounce are published in the Federal Register, and his name has not been found there so far.

Comment: @user102008 but the lists in the federal register are apparently not comprehensive, and the criteria for inclusion are not published, and are the subject of debate. So his absence from the federal register doesn't mean that he didn't renounce it.  It just seems that there is no way to know for certain.

Comment: @cpast, user102008: of course, now that Boris is foreign minister, which *is* a policy-level position in the government of a foreign state, if he hasn't already renounced he'll have to overcome the presumption that he did intend to lose his US citizenship when taking the post.

Comment: @phoog: There is no "presumption that he did intend to lose his US citizenship". The US government has the burden of proving, by preponderance of evidence, that he intends to lose US citizenship in order for him to lose US citizenship.

Comment: @user102008 I see.  His repeated assertions of intent to renounce his US citizenship are unlikely to help him in that regard.

Comment: @user102008 Then again, the US is unlikely to attempt to deprive him of his citizenship given his history of paying large tax bills.

Comment: Committing treason does not give rise to a loss of citizenship and can only be committed by a citizen. Otherwise, generally correct.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm quite sure I took treason from the state department page, but the link is dead now.  I'll fix the answer in a couple of days.  I'll also try to find BJ's mention in the federal register, since he did finally get around to renouncing.

Comment: @ohwilleke the mention of treason must have been in reference to [8 USC 1481(a)(7)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1481#a_7).  The fact that treason can only be committed by a citizen is surely unimportant in the discussion of whether it can cause a loss of citizenship, because a loss of citizenship is also only possible for a citizen.  In light of 8 USC 1481(a)(7), though, why does treason not give rise to a loss of citizenship?

Comment: @phoog I stand corrected. I guess in a case of treason carried out in favor of a foreign state you would be assumed to have loyalty to the foreign state. There is an issue logically with rendering someone stateless in a case of a insurrection, but I guess one could be a non-citizen national. Usually a core incident of non-citizenship is deportability which would seem impossible in the case of a stateless former U.S. citizen by birth in the U.S. to U.S. parents who committed an insurrection, but I guess that wouldn't have to be so (and of course, this statute has little case law).

Comment: @ohwilleke one can be deportable under the INA (that is, meet the criteria it establishes) even if in practice there's nowhere to deport the person to. (For similar reasons, asylum seekers in France sometimes throw away their identity papers and lie about their nationality.) I note that 8 USC 1481 speaks of loss of nationality, not citizenship, so it wouldn't leave someone as a non-citizen national. There's still the "intention" element, perhaps oddly, and the subsection (b) burden of proof on the party claiming the loss. If neither party claims the loss occurred, it would not occur.

Comment: @cpast Boris appears to be listed among those whose loss of citizenship was reported to the Secretary of the Treasury during the [last quarter of 2016](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2018/05/08/2018-09709/quarterly-publication-of-individuals-who-have-chosen-to-expatriate-as-required-by-section-6039g).

Comment: @cpast Oops, wrong link.  Here's the correct one: https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2017/02/09/2017-02699/quarterly-publication-of-individuals-who-have-chosen-to-expatriate-as-required-by-section-6039g.

Answer (score 3):

For a natural-born citizen, the only realistic way to lose your citizenship is through voluntary renunciation. To do that, the person must be over 18 years old, and must appear in person at a US consulate. It cannot be done on US soil, it cannot be done under duress, it cannot be done by anybody under 18, and it cannot be done by anybody but the person themself.

This is actually a problem for some children born on US soil to Indian parents who plan to return to India. India does not allow dual citizenship, and requires that the child renounce their US citizenship in order to retain Indian citizenship. But that is impossible to do under US law.

I believe there also are theoretical mechanisms that could be used in cases of treason or voluntarily working in a foreign government or enlistment in a foreign military, but in practice I don't think this ever happens. The Supreme Court made a series of decisions that basically threw out most, if not all, of these laws.

In real life, there are quite a few US citizen foreign dignitaries. Queen Noor of Jordan comes to mind. Also, Mohamed Abdullahi Mohamed became President of Somalia while still a US citizen (he later did renounce his US citizenship).

That doesn't mean that the US government hasn't tried extralegal means to strip somebody of US citizenship. During WW II, many Japanese-Americans had been pressured to renounce their US citizenship. Those renunciations were all later overturned. More recently, the Taliban member Yaser Esam Hamdi was born in Louisiana, and therefore a natural-born US citizen. The US government forced him to renounce his US citizenship. If he wanted to pursue that, that renunciation would be almost certainly be considered invalid, so he probably still is a US citizen. Of course, odds are that this case won't ever end up in any court. It might come up, for instance if he has children who claim derivative US citizenship.

For naturalized citizens, citizenship can also be revoked if the citizenship was obtained fraudulently. That is usually the process used for revoking the citizenship of former Nazis who had failed to disclose their background when they immigrated.

Comment: As far as I understand the Indian situation, the dual national child born abroad may retain Indian nationality by never applying for a foreign passport.  This could be a problem for those who plan to remain in the foreign country for several years but not permanently.  In practice, it seems, most opt for the foreign citizenship and OCI, which ought to allow the child to regain Indian citizenship fairly easily, if desired, after turning 18.

Comment: The supreme court did not throw out the laws that define various expatriating acts, but established that nobody may be involuntarily deprived of US nationality through such an act.  It's still theoretically possible to lose US nationality by performing such an act and documenting one's intention to lose US nationality thereby.  Also, while Nazis are the most prominent examples, there are certainly others who have been denaturalized after fraudulently obtaining US citizenship.

Comment: @phoog Without knowing Indian law in detail, of course you may be right. That said, it would be unusual by international standards. Very often, people colloquially say "apply for XYZ password" when they really mean "apply for XYZ citizenship". In that case, "never applying" would be impossible because the child would have US citizenship from birth. In any case, not applying for a US passport would not change anything, because the child would then be unable to leave the US, and therefore even after age 18 unable to renounce US citizenship. The person cannot travel on an Indian passport alone.

Comment: It certainly is unusual by international standards.  And as far as I recall the Indian courts have established the precedent concerning the passport application, something like they won't hold your other citizenship from birth against you unless you actually take steps to exercise some right pertaining to that citizenship.  I looked into this 11 years ago when my nephew was born (his father was an Indian citizen at the time). There are several questions and answers on the topic at [Travel.SE] and/or [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Furthermore, in practice, a dual citizen of the US and another country has no trouble to leave the US without a US passport, so your assessment that the child would effectively be stuck in the US is incorrect.  (Also, after turning 18, the child could lose US citizenship without leaving the US, though it would take some legal creativity.)